# Placing subheader header rows onto top-level report SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to implement an SSRS report without showing repeated subreport headers in each subreport shown in the top-level report, when it runs.

But I still want to show the top-level header on the first header row of the top-level report, the top-level header's columns of which correspond to each subreport's columns of course.

How would I go about implementing this?

Comment: Can you post an image of what the report current looks like and what you'd like to remove? Also can you include the minimum report XML to generate the report with example data. I use the format `SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('', '')) tbl ([Column1], [Column2])` when I need to use example data in SQL Server. What version of SSRS are you using? What database are you using?

Comment: Are your subreports being generated in a Tablix, by that I mean to do you have a Tablix and each row pass a subreport with parameters from the Tablix dataset? If so this should be easy, just pass the rownumber from the Tablix dataset as a parameter to the subreport and where that rownumber is 1 hide the header row (row visibility)

Comment: @AlanSchofield this technique worked.  thank you very much Alan.